# Preg_match pattern inside tag with regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use a regex to find a string. For example, my text is :

```
$text="<h2>Introduction of Abdominal aortic aneurysm</h2>
<p>In this section, we will learn about symptom, causes, and treatment of 
AAA</p>
<h2>This is Treatment for a burst AAA</h2><p>.......<p>
<h2>.........</h2>"
```

I want to find :

```
$temp="<h2>This is Treatment for a burst AAA</h2>
<p>.......<p>"
```

I try this pattern :

```
Preg_match("/<h2(.*?)Treatment(.*?)<h2>/i",$text,$matches);
```

if i echo $matches[1] it will return:

```
"Introduction of Abdominal aortic aneurysm</h2>
<p> In this section, we will learn about symptom, causes, and "
```

and if i echo $matches[2] it will return:

```
" of AAA<p>"
```

how to get $matches that match to this sentence :

```
"<h2>This is Treatment for a burst AAA</h2>"
```

Actually i want to make a pattern that match a text inside a  tag not a

tag.

Comment: Don't just post pictures. Write your question in the post.

Comment: Please read [ask], then [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] (this means, your _code must be in the question itself, **and your actual question must be in the question itself**_).

Comment: how to post question with a tag. it change my text. My <h2> tag will return a bold text

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a [regex to parse your html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), you might use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [C14N](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.c14n.php):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$text="<h2>Introduction of Abdominal aortic aneurysm</h2>
<p>In this section, we will learn about symptom, causes, and treatment of 
AAA</p>
<h2>This is Treatment for a burst AAA</h2><p>.......<p>
<h2>.........</h2>";

$dom->loadHTML($text);
$elms = $dom->getElementsByTagName("h2");
foreach($elms as $elm) {
    if (strstr($elm->nodeValue, "Treatment") !== false) {
        echo $elm->C14N();
    }
}
```

That will result in:

```
<h2>This is Treatment for a burst AAA</h2>
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/FkCDr)